# Ideas for modelling an asset tree with relationships and time frames in Azure Data Explorer and displaying in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, azure-data-explorer

My data lives in Azure Data Explorer. I have two tables, one with assets and one with relationships (of the assets). The Asset table has an unique id, name, activeFrom and activeTo columns. The Relationships table has an unique id, sourceId, targetId, activeFrom and activeTo columns. The sourceId and targetId correspond to ids from the Asset table. Ultimately, I'm looking to flatten this hierarchy so that I can display roll-up values in PowerBI. I've partially been able to achieve this using a graph query below (simplified example). I have taken the activeFrom and activeTo columns of the Relationships table into account, but I would also like to take into account the same columns from the Asset table. I want to figure out the best way to do this. So far my ideas have been:

1. Direct query for a single date (should be able to implement but does not allow for date rollups)
2. Use MV-expand and the range function on the activeFrom and activeTo to get an activeDates column for each hierarchy row (not sure how to combine the activeFrom and activeTo from the Assets table)
3. Possibly use active & inactive relationships in PowerBI and calculated measures/columns for the roll-ups?

```
let hierarchyAssets=datatable (['id']: guid, name: string, activeFrom: datetime, activeTo: datetime) [
    guid(d1384514-8ce5-4536-84b6-f6009bb64258),"Level 1",datetime(2023-10-01T00:00:00Z),datetime(2023-12-20T00:00:00Z),
    guid(55d6daf1-8726-4e51-8c77-66ef3d5a0fb1),"Asset 2",datetime(2023-11-01T00:00:00Z),datetime(null),
    guid(785310d7-d9c9-46d3-b1be-8e56a35c76b0),"Asset 3",datetime(2023-12-01T00:00:00Z),datetime(2023-12-13T00:00:00Z)
];
let hierarchyRelationships=datatable (['id']: guid, sourceId: guid, targetId: guid, activeFrom: datetime, activeTo: datetime, targetAsset: string) [
    guid(5a2abf0d-75ee-4929-9e0a-8de7ac99ac78),guid(55d6daf1-8726-4e51-8c77-66ef3d5a0fb1),guid(d1384514-8ce5-4536-84b6-f6009bb64258),datetime(2023-10-01T00:00:00Z),datetime(null),"Level 1",
    guid(0da8a18e-59d4-4ed3-b62e-2de337068fa3),guid(785310d7-d9c9-46d3-b1be-8e56a35c76b0),guid(d1384514-8ce5-4536-84b6-f6009bb64258),datetime(2023-10-01T00:00:00Z),datetime(2023-11-30T00:00:00Z),"Level 1",
    guid(414cb1c1-34dc-4103-b6dc-76eef6f722c8),guid(785310d7-d9c9-46d3-b1be-8e56a35c76b0),guid(55d6daf1-8726-4e51-8c77-66ef3d5a0fb1),datetime(2023-12-01T00:00:00Z),datetime(null),"Asset 2"
];
let rootAssets = hierarchyAssets
| where id in ((hierarchyRelationships | project targetId)) and id !in ((hierarchyRelationships | project sourceId));
hierarchyRelationships
| make-graph sourceId --> targetId with hierarchyAssets on id
| graph-match (parentAsset)<-[belongs*1..10]-(asset)
where parentAsset.id in ((rootAssets | project id))
project assetName=split(asset.name,''),hierarchy=belongs.targetAsset,assetId=asset.id,activeFrom=belongs.activeFrom,activeTo=belongs.activeTo
| extend hierarchy=array_concat(hierarchy,assetName)
| union (rootAssets | project assetName=pack_array(name),hierarchy=pack_array(name),assetId=id)
| project Level0=hierarchy[0],Level1=hierarchy[1],Level2=hierarchy[2],Path=replace_strings(tostring(hierarchy),dynamic([@',',@'[',@']',@'"']),dynamic([@'\',@'\\',@'',@''])),assetName=tostring(assetName[0]),assetId,activeFrom=coalesce(todatetime(activeFrom[-1]),datetime(1970-01-01)),activeTo=coalesce(todatetime(activeTo[-1]),startofday(now(1d)))
```